# Bean already registered - struts2-core dependency error

Tags: java, spring, maven, struts2, dependency-management

I'm trying to migrate a project to Maven and declare Struts 2 dependencies, but I'm stuck at this error. I already double-checked the `pom.xml` dependencies, made sure `struts2-core` is only declared once, added exclusions and all. I tried also with and without `xwork-core` dependency, same error. I am literally stuck and don't know how to proceed here.

**My error:**

```
15:35:29,079 INFO  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
    15:35:29,124 ERROR [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) Dispatcher initialization failed: Unable to load configuration. - bean - vfs:/C:/servers/JBoss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments/war.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.jar/struts-default.xml:40:72
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:416) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3225) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3791) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [rt.jar:1.6.0_13]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_13]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_13]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_13]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_13]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_13]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
    Caused by: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - vfs:/C:/servers/JBoss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments/war.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.jar/struts-default.xml:40:72
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name struts has already been loaded by bean - vfs:/C:/servers/JBoss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments/war.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar/struts-default.xml:40:72 - bean - vfs:/C:/servers/JBoss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments/war.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.jar/struts-default.xml:40:72
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:229) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        ... 20 more
    
    15:35:29,134 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/fordaq]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) JBWEB000284: Exception starting filter struts: Unable to load configuration. - bean - vfs:/C:/servers/JBoss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments/war.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.jar/struts-default.xml:40:72
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:501) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:416) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3225) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3791) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [rt.jar:1.6.0_13]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_13]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_13]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_13]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_13]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_13]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
    Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - vfs:/C:/servers/JBoss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments/war.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.jar/struts-default.xml:40:72
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - vfs:/C:/servers/JBoss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments/war.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.jar/struts-default.xml:40:72
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name struts has already been loaded by bean - vfs:/C:/servers/JBoss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments/war.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar/struts-default.xml:40:72 - bean - vfs:/C:/servers/JBoss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments/war.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.jar/struts-default.xml:40:72
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:229) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
        ... 20 more
```

**`pom.xml` with the dependencies:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-struts1-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.16</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add `struts2-core` artifact and test it if it works, then add Spring and/or other plugins. See how to [Create Struts 2 Web Application Using Maven To Manage Artifacts and To Build The Application](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html).

The `pom.xml` for core struts2 application requires only

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>X.X.X.X</version>
</dependency>
```

where `X.X.X.X` is for concrete version, i.e. `2.3.16.3` or `2.3.24.1`,
and it will download all other dependencies. Integrating with other frameworks use plugins and don't mess up dependencies that are duplicated. Clean, rebuild, redeploy. Check `WEB-INF/lib` it should not contain duplicate libraries from different versions. In your case
`struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar` and `struts2-core-2.3.16.jar` both are loaded on classpath. This is error, there should not be the same library of two different versions.

You also use other plugins

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.16.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.16.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-struts1-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.16.3</version>
</dependency>
```

that could be added to the `pom.xml`.